# Why do I get `CGPathGetCurrentPoint: no current point.` when I try to draw a UIBezierpath in context?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibezierpath, bezier

I'm trying to draw my bezier path in a context using this method which uses an array full of CGPoints for drawing a smooth path across them and I've used NSLog to make sure the array isn't NULL and it isn't but I keep getting this error which says: : `CGPathGetCurrentPoint: no current point.` 
and it doesn't draw anything on my UIView. What should I do? Thanks in advance.

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self drawBezier:rect inContext:context];  
}

- (void)drawBezier:(CGRect)rect inContext:(CGContextRef)context {
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    //< Start and End Point
    if (self.pointCount < 2)
    {
        return;
    }

    CGPoint startPt = [[self.pointsArray objectAtIndex:0] CGPointValue];
    CGPoint endPt = [[self.pointsArray objectAtIndex:(self.pointCount - 1)] CGPointValue];

    float amount = endPt.x - startPt.x;

    int (^factorial)(int k) = ^(int k) {
        if (k == 0)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        int m = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++)
        {
            m *= i;
        }
        return m;
    };


    //< Curve Equation
    float (^bezierSpline)(int rank, float ux) = ^(int rank, float ux) {

        float p = 0.0f;

        for (int i = 0; i < rank; i++)
        {
            CGPoint pt = [[self.pointsArray objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue];

            p += pt.y * powf((1 - ux), (rank - i - 1)) * powf(ux, i) * (factorial(rank - 1) / (factorial(i) * factorial(rank - i - 1)));
        }

        return p;
    };
    [path moveToPoint:startPt];

    for (float curX = startPt.x; (curX - endPt.x) < 1e-5; curX += 1.0f)
    {
        float u = (curX - startPt.x) / amount;
        [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(curX, bezierSpline(self.pointCount, u))];
    }

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0f);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
    CGContextAddPath(context, path.CGPath);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement touch begin method something like,

```
  - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

UITouch *mytouch=[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
[_path moveToPoint:[mytouch locationInView:self]];  // self is view here. you can pass  relevant view


 }
```

`_path` is instance variable of `UIBezierPath`. don't take it as local!

Comment: I've filled my array by getting all the CGPoints by user touches in touchesBegan and touchesMoved and touchesEnded methods before and then I try to redraw the whole path by using the `drawBezier:(CGRect)rect inContext:(CGContextRef)context` using all the points i got from user's touch because it will redraw it in a smooth way and I call this method in drawRect when the user has finished drawing the uibezierpath using touchesBegan and other conventional methods and I'm stuck in redrawing it using my method.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're calling `CGPathGetCurrentPoint` (or calling something that, itself, calls `CGPathGetCurrentPoint`), when the path hasn't started. For example, you get that error if you call `addLineToPoint` before calling `moveToPoint`, but I don't see this code doing that.

I'd suggest you add some breakpoints and or log statements to identify what line is causing this error. I cannot reproduce the error you report on the basis of the code provided.

---

Unrelated, I'd suggest retiring the `CGContext` functions altogether, e.g. replacing the lines:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0f);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
CGContextAddPath(context, path.CGPath);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

With:

```
path.lineWidth = 1;
[[UIColor whiteColor] setStroke];
[path stroke];
```

Comment: I've filled my array by getting all the CGPoints by user touches in touchesBegan and touchesMoved and touchesEnded methods before and then I try to redraw the whole path by using the `drawBezier:(CGRect)rect inContext:(CGContextRef)context` using all the points i got from user's touch because it will redraw it in a smooth way and I call this method in drawRect when the user has finished drawing the uibezierpath using touchesBegan and other conventional methods and I'm stuck in redrawing it using my method.

Comment: And yes of course UIBezierpaths draw in it's own context but I really dont know how can i redraw it without using context in my code. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Understood, but the problem does not occur in the code sample you shared with us. It must occur somewhere else. We need a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem in order to help you. I'd suggest trying to build a MCVE from scratch that reproduces the problem. Until we can reproduce the problem, we can't help you. But your error suggests that somewhere you're calling `addLineToPoint` without having first called `moveToPoint`.

Comment: Regarding `UIBezierPath` method `stroke`, when you call that, it retrieves the current graphics context, and then strokes it. In short, it does the exact same thing as your Core Graphics calls, but it's just more concise.

Comment: Actually I'm implementing UIPinchGestureRecognizer on its superview when the draw is finished so the user can pinchzoom the UIView with the bezier drawn inside it but I dont really think this error has anything to do with it and my code is gonna be like.... really long if I wanna share the whole code im using in this class. But I'm gonna update the code in here as much as the same error still happens in it. Thank you. @Rob